# Memento Pattern between sister classes

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, memento

The following is my usage of the Memento Pattern when one class uses the copy constructor of a sister class (a separate derived class of the base class) and wishes to revert to the previous class.  Note that `allMementos` is a map of Mementos instead of just a single Memento because of possible multiple conversions between many sister classes, so all the previous values of the many different multiple classes need to be stored.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <typeindex>

struct Person {
    struct Memento { virtual ~Memento() = default; };
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::type_index, Memento*> allMementos;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) { }
    virtual ~Person() = default;
protected:
    template <typename T> void addMemento (Memento* memento) { allMementos[typeid(T)] = memento; }  // Replaces the previous Memento*, allMementos[typeid(T)] (if it exsited before), with the new Memento* since the old one is now out-of-date and no longer needed.  If it didn't exist before, then it is inserted into map as std::map's [] operator does.
    template <typename T> typename T::Memento* findMemento() const;
    template <typename T> void reinstateMemento();
private:
    virtual void reinstateMementoHook (const Memento*) = 0;
};

struct Singer;

struct TennisFan : Person {
    struct Memento : Person::Memento { 
        std::string favouriteTennisTournament;  // Add whatever other data members are in TennisFan but not in any base class of TennisFan.
        Memento (const TennisFan* t) : favouriteTennisTournament(t->favouriteTennisTournament) { }
    };
    std::string favouriteTennisTournament;  // Plus whatever other data members.
    TennisFan (const std::string& name, const std::string& f) : Person(name), favouriteTennisTournament(f) { }
    TennisFan (const Singer&, const std::string& = "");
    void changeFavouriteTennisTournament (const std::string& f) { favouriteTennisTournament = f; }
    Memento* createMemento() const { return new Memento(this); }
private:
    virtual void reinstateMementoHook (const Person::Memento*) override;
};

struct Singer : Person {
    struct Memento : Person::Memento { 
        int numSongsPerformed;  // Add whatever other data members are in Singer but not in any base class of Singer.
        Memento (const Singer* s) : numSongsPerformed(s->numSongsPerformed) { }
    };
    int numSongsPerformed;  // Plus whatever other data members.
    Singer (const std::string& name, int n) : Person(name), numSongsPerformed(n) { }
    Singer (const TennisFan&, int = 0);
    void addSongsPerformed (int num) { numSongsPerformed += num; }
    Memento* createMemento() const { return new Memento(this); }
private:
    virtual void reinstateMementoHook (const Person::Memento*) override;
};

template <typename T>
typename T::Memento* Person::findMemento() const {
    std::map<std::type_index, Memento*>::const_iterator it = allMementos.find(typeid(T));
    if (it == allMementos.end())
        return nullptr;  // No memento found means that no change in type was made before.
    return dynamic_cast<typename T::Memento*>(it->second);
}

template <typename T>
void Person::reinstateMemento() {
    const typename T::Memento* memento = findMemento<T>();
    if (!memento)
        return;  // Nothing to reinstate, because 'this' was not a Singer before.
    reinstateMementoHook(memento);
}

TennisFan::TennisFan (const Singer& singer, const std::string& f) : Person(singer), favouriteTennisTournament(f) {
    addMemento<Singer>(singer.createMemento());
    reinstateMemento<TennisFan>();
}

void TennisFan::reinstateMementoHook (const Person::Memento* m) {
    const Memento* memento = dynamic_cast<const Memento*>(m);
    favouriteTennisTournament = memento->favouriteTennisTournament;
    // Resore whatever other data members exist in TennisFan but not in any base class of TennisFan.
}

Singer::Singer (const TennisFan& tennisFan, int n) : Person(tennisFan), numSongsPerformed(n) {
    addMemento<TennisFan>(tennisFan.createMemento());
    reinstateMemento<Singer>();
}

void Singer::reinstateMementoHook (const Person::Memento* m) {
    const Memento* memento = dynamic_cast<const Memento*>(m);
    numSongsPerformed = memento->numSongsPerformed;
    // Resore whatever other data members exist in Singer but not in any base class of Singer.
}

int main() {
    TennisFan samTennisLover("Sam", "Wimbledon");
    std::cout << samTennisLover.name << "'s faourite tennis tournament is " << samTennisLover.favouriteTennisTournament << ".\n";
    Singer samTheSinger(samTennisLover, 20);  // Sam no longer likes Tennis, and instead is a singer now, with 20 sung songs already under his belt.
    std::cout << samTheSinger.name << " no longer likes tennis, and is now a singer with " << samTheSinger.numSongsPerformed << " songs performed.\n";
    samTennisLover = TennisFan(samTheSinger);  // Sam goes back to liking Tennis instead of singing.
    std::cout << samTennisLover.name << " is a tennis fan again, and his faourite tennis tournament is " << samTennisLover.favouriteTennisTournament << ", as before.\n";
    samTennisLover.changeFavouriteTennisTournament("French Open");
    std::cout << samTennisLover.name << "'s faourite tennis tournament is now " << samTennisLover.favouriteTennisTournament << ".\n";
    samTheSinger = Singer(samTennisLover);
    std::cout << samTheSinger.name << " no longer likes tennis, and is back to being a singer with " << samTheSinger.numSongsPerformed << " songs performed, as before.\n";
    samTheSinger.addSongsPerformed(30);
    std::cout << samTheSinger.name << " has sung 30 more songs, and thus now has " << samTheSinger.numSongsPerformed << " songs performed.\n";
    samTennisLover = TennisFan(samTheSinger);
    std::cout << samTennisLover.name << " is a tennis fan again, and his faourite tennis tournament is " << samTennisLover.favouriteTennisTournament << ", as before.\n";
    samTheSinger = Singer(samTennisLover);
    std::cout << samTheSinger.name << " no longer likes tennis, and is back to being a singer with " << samTheSinger.numSongsPerformed << " songs performed, as before.\n"; 
}

Output:
Sam's faourite tennis tournament is Wimbledon.
Sam no longer likes tennis, and is now a singer with 20 songs performed.
Sam is a tennis fan again, and his faourite tennis tournament is Wimbledon, as before.
Sam's faourite tennis tournament is now French Open.
Sam no longer likes tennis, and is back to being a singer with 20 songs performed, as before.
Sam has sung 30 more songs, and thus now has 50 songs performed.
Sam is a tennis fan again, and his faourite tennis tournament is French Open, as before.
Sam no longer likes tennis, and is back to being a singer with 50 songs performed, as before.
```

Answer (score 1):

## This is not a good example

> The following is my usage of the Memento Pattern when one class uses the copy constructor of a sister class (a separate derived class of the base class) and wishes to revert to the previous class.

You can't revert a `class` to another `class` in C++. Your example actually creates two named `Person` objects, and you copy state between them using the copy constructor (the first time) and the copy assignment operator (all subsequent times). There are also temporary objects involved. It makes the example very unclear.

Another issue is that `Memento`s are not deleted when a `Person` object is deleted. You could solve that by adding a destructor that goes over every item in `allMemento`s and calling `delete` on them, but raw `new` and `delete` is frowned upon. I thought that a simple fix would be to make the map store [`std::unique_ptr<Memento>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)s, but that quickly runs into problems because of the fact that you are using copy assignment in the example.

A better solution would be to have an abstract `class Profession`, and have `Singer` and `TennisFan` derive from that. Then a `Person` can be a concrete class that has a `current_profession` state, and a map of `past_professions` caretaker:

```
class Profession {
    virtual ~Profession();
};

class Singer: public Profession {
    ...
};

class TennisFan: public Profession {
    ...
};

class Person {
    std::string name;
    std::unique_ptr<Profession> current_profession;
    std::unordered_map<std::typeid, std::unique_ptr<Profession>> past_professions;

public:
    Person(const std::string& name): name(name) {}
    template<typename T, typename... Args> void setProfession(Args&&... args);
    template<typename T = Profession> T* getProfession();
    template<typename T> void reinstateProfession();
};
```

The implementation of the functions changing the profession would look like:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> void Person::setProfession(Args&&... args) {
    if (current_profession) {
        past_professions[typeid(*current_profession)] = std::move(current_profession);
    }

    current_profession = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename T> T* Persion::getProfession() {
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(currentProfession.get());
}

template<typename T> void Person::reinstateProfession() {
    current_profession = std::move(past_professions.at(typeid(T)));
}
```

And one could use it like so:

```
Person sam("Sam");
sam.setProfession<TennisLover>("Wimbledon");
std::cout << sam.name << "'s favourite tennis tournament is "
          << sam.getProfession<TennisLover>()->favouriteTennisTournament
          << ".\n";
sam.setProfession<Singer>(20);
std::cout << sam.name << " is now a singer with "
          << sam.getProfession<Singer>()->numSongsPerformed
          << " songs performed.\n";
sam.reinstateProfession<TennisLover>();
std::cout << sam.name << " is now a tennis fan again, his favourite is "
          << sam.getProfession<TennisLover>()->favouriteTennisTournament
          << ".\n";
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I chose TennisFan instead of TennisPlayer to convince readers that Profession is not something they can derive from.  I'm writing a fantasy type game where objects can morph into vastly different and unrelated types and revert back, hence my use of copy constructor and Memento.

Comment: Still, if a property of a person can change, it definitely does not have an ["is-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship with that property, but rather a ["has-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a).